# Trouble implementing a proper (underflow protected) pop/peek method in the stack using liked lists

Tags: c++, stack, stackunderflow

OK, I'm trying to write the stack pop method using linked lists for my C++ homework.
Let me just show you the node and list classes first, then tell you the problem:

```
class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;

    Node(int data, Node* next = 0)
    {
        this->data = data;
        this->next = next;
    }
};
class List
{
private:
  Node* head; // no need for the tail when using the list for implementing a stack

public:
    List()
    {
        head = 0;
    }
    void add_to_head(int  data)
    {
        if(head == 0)
        {
            head = new Node(data);
        }
        else 
        {
            head = new Node(data, head);
        }
    }

    Node* get_head()
    {
        return head;
    }

    // this deletes the head element and makes 'head' points to the node after it.
    void delete_head()
    {
        // storing the head so that we could delete it afterwards.
        Node* temp = head;

        // making the head point to the next element.
        head = temp->next;

        // freeing memory from the deleted head.
        delete(temp);
    }
};
```

Now here's the stack:

```
class stack
{
private: 
    List* list;

public:
  stack()
  {
      list = new List();
      flush();
  }
  void push(int value)
  {
      list->add_to_head(value);
  }
  bool pop(int& value_to_fill)
  {
      if(is_empty())
      {
        return false; // underflow...
      }

      value_to_fill = list->get_head()->data;

     // deleting the head. NOTE that head will automatically point to the next element after deletion 
     // (check out the delete_head definition)
     list->delete_head();

     return true; // popping succeed.
  }
  bool peek(int& value_to_fill)
  {
    if(is_empty())
    {
       return false;
    }
    value_to_fill = list->get_head()->data;
    return true;
  }
 // other stuff...
};
```

Now the problem is with pop and peek, I just don't find them to be convenient. 
pop and peek shouldn't be given any parameters, but if I do this:

```
int peek()
{
  if(is_empty())
    // what should I do here?
  return list->get_head()->data;
}
int pop()
{
  if(is_empty())
    // same thing here.

  // deleting the tos then returning it.
  // I know this is not what the pop in the STL stack does, but I like it this way
    int tos = list->get_head()->data;
    list->delete_head();
    return tos;
}
```

I don't know what to do when an underflow occurs.
I can't just return -1 or 0 or something like that, cuz this will look like as if I popped -1 or 0 (tos == -1 or 0)
Is there a way of writing an anti-underflow pop/peek without having to pass anything by reference?

Comment: They say exceptions are nice.

Comment: Don't you want to use hated lists instead?

Comment: @doublep: Well, from what I know (from C#) that you can't do this:
int peek()
{
 try
 {
  return list->get_head()->data;
 }
 catch(...)
 {}
}
you'll get an error saying that all paths must return something.
But I just tried it in C++ and it worked! It compiled without any errors. Shouldn't it give me that error?

Comment: @Vexe It's only an error in C++ if the code actually takes that path.  It's hard for the compiler to determine that, so no error message is required.  (It's called undefined behavior.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a question of specification.  There are several possible solutions:

- Make it a pre-condition of `pop` that the stack isn't empty.  It is
  the client's responsibility to ensure this (perhaps by calling
  `is_empty()` before popping), and a violation of the precondition
  results in an assertion failure.
- Throw an exception if the stack is empty.  This is the most obvious
  solution, but probably the least generally applicable.
- Don't have `pop` return a value (or have it return your `bool`).  To
  get the top element, you have a separate function, `tos()`, and a client
  who wants to do both needs two function calls: `x = s.tos(); s.pop();`.
  This is what the standard does, for example.  In practice, it is often
  the preferred method, because for types where copying can throw (e.g.
  `std::string`), it's impossible to implement pop to return a value and
  give the strong exception guarantee.  (Whether this is a problem or not
  is another issue, but it could be a problem in specific cases, and it is
  the motivation behind the choice in the standard, where none of the pop
  functions return a value.)

In the end, the important thing is for you to define the interface, so
that your user knows what to expect.

And by the way, you don't need the `if` in `add_to_head`.  If `head ==
NULL`,  you're going to call the constructor with the second argument
`NULL`, so you might as well just pass `head` in both cases.

(I'll skip the fact that using a linked list is a remarkably inefficient
way to implement a stack, since the code is obviously a learning
exercise.)

Comment: Couldn't have been said better. But what is the best way to implement a stack? using an array? Yes, as you guessed, I'm just training on linked lists.

Comment: @VeXe I'd use `std::vector` normally, with `push_back`, `pop_back` and `back` to implement push, pop and tos.